# Installing tflite-support-nightly package fails with "No matching distribution found"

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-lite

I'm learning on how to set metadata and previously used this link step-by-step and it worked perfectly. I'm focusing on Object Detection.

Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/models/convert/metadata_writer_tutorial.ipynb

Issue I'm experiencing is:

```
!pip install tflite-support-nightly
```

Started returning error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tflite-support-nightly (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tflite-support-nightly
```

I'm sure that it worked well a week ago or so. Any ideas on how to fix colab code to make it working? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by using: Colab’s fallback runtime version
It sets python version back to 3.9 that runs perfectly.